# Difference between GPVM and LVM when referencing virtual servers?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-esx

I've been advised that there are two types of VMs available for enterprise use, but unfortunately have not been able to identify any resources that can explain what these are.

The pricing between the two types is substantial with LVM seemingly costing more.

*In this circumstance, I don't think LVM refers to "Logical Volume Management".*

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you constrain this question to "enterprise use", empirically I would say that the two types are VMware based or Xen based.

When you refer to LVM in the virtual machine context (**NOTE**: I think you mean KVM), it would most likely be the acronym for a ["Kernel-Based virtual machine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor).

I would assume that GPVM stands for "General Purpose virtual machine", though I've never used GPVM before. So it might be a more academic term.